# Rsync excluding everything except 1 directory tree

Tags: linux, rsync

I have a directory structure with a variable number of subdirectories and files. I would like to exclude everything EXCEPT 1 subdirectory tree.

I have tried

```
rsync -a --include 'wanted_dir' --exclude '*' 1/ 2/
```

but it gives me just the `wanted_dir` directory (none of the files under it).

Comment: Your question is ambigiuos.explain more and clearly

Answer (score 7):

To include all files within your directory, add the triple stars :

```
rsync -a --include 'wanted_dir/***' --exclude '*' 1/ 2/
```

Comment: For some reason, using cygwin to rsync from a linux box to the windows workstation, I had to add three stars to the exclude, to make it exclude all except the tar files. Thanks. `rsync -a --include '*.tar' --exclude '***' r@lin:/dir local/dir`

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't it make more sense to just add that to the include dir?

```
rsync -a --include 'wanted_dir/1/'
```

What's happening in your code that would make you need to include the root dir?

Comment: I got what I wanted with : rsync -av  1/wanted_dir 2/